# How to turn error message into a bool value?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, boolean

```
i=5
while bool(controller[i]):
    controller_jsn['Transition']=controller[i]
    i+=1
```

I write a code above. And try to stop the loop when `i` is out of range. bool() is not the way. what methode should I use?

Comment: what do you mean out of range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common way to write this code would be to iterate over the elements directly, instead of using indices. Use a slice if you need to start at the 5th element instead of looping over all elements.

```
for c in controller[5:]:
    controller_jsn['Transition'] = c
```

but I hope you have more logic in there, because each iteration of the loop just overwrites the same value.